# How to make an associative array in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET project. I want to make an associative array consisting of username and password. Since I am making hardcoded login for a trial. I have a class called `Profile`:

```
public class Profile
{
    private string _UserName;
    private string _Password;

    public string UserName 
    {
        get { return _UserName; }
        set { _UserName = value; }
    }

    public string Password 
    {
        get { return _Password; }
        set { _Password = value; }
    }
}
```

Then in `Login.ASPX.cs`, I want to make an associative array so it can login.

```
Profile pr;
pr = new Profile() { UserName = "trick", Password = "tricker" }, new User() {UserName = "big", Password = "bigger" };
```

How to make this code work by making it an associative array?

Comment: Usually you use a Dictionary[String, String] for this. Have you tried those? The 2nd way is to make a class, struct or tupel of 2 strings, then make a array/list of those.

Comment: @Christopher Can you guide me in this, I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Wich of the 2 Operations? What have your tried? What dod you expect to happen? What is happening or not happening instead?

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing to make it work. Please add code that compiles; `Profile =  pr` and `pr =...` do not compute.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a list?

```
List<Profile> pr;
pr = new List<Profile>(){
    new Profile() { UserName = "trick", Password = "tricker" },
    new Profile() { UserName = "big", Password = "bigger" }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `UserName` is unique here, so I suggest to use `Dictionary` instead of `List`:

```
 private static Dictionary<string, Profile> sessions;
```

So that you can easily do Login/Logoff operations:

-> Checking person if already login

```
sessions.ContainsKey("trick");
```

-> Adding Login person to Dictionary

```
Person newPerson = new Profile() { UserName = "trick", Password = "tricker" };
sessions.Add(newPerson.UserName, newPerson);
```

-> Removing person from the Dictionary

```
sessions.Remove("trick");
```